# Calculating the average number of exons per transcript

Tags: awk, average

I want to be able to **calculate the average number of *exons* per *transcript*** in my file.

*FYI only:* The file format I am working with is called a [GENCODE GTF](https://www.gencodegenes.org/pages/data_format.html) file.

To find the number of exons per transcript, we must search within the semicolon-separated list of field 9 (`$9`), but only for lines of *exonic features* (lines where the string "`exon`" is in field 3 (`$3`)) of the tab-delimited file.

Each unique `transcript_id` has a series of associated exonic feature lines with increasing number of "`exon_number n`" within field 9 (`$9`):

```
...; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; ...; exon_number 1; ...
...; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; ...; exon_number 2; ...
...
...; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; ...; exon_number n; ...
```

To get the *average* number of exons per transcript, simply add the maximum `exon_number` from each unique `trasnscript_id`, then divide by the total number of unique `transcript_id` used.

---

**Here are the 10 possible formats for any given line in my file:**

```
chr19   HAVANA   gene   405438   409170   .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3";
chr19   HAVANA   transcript   405438   409170   .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
chr19   HAVANA   exon   409006   409170   .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001322986.5"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
chr19   HAVANA   exon   405438   408401   .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001290344.6"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
chr19   HAVANA   CDS   407099   408361   .   -   0   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001290344.6"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
chr19   HAVANA   start_codon   408359   408361   .   -   0   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001290344.6"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
chr19   HAVANA   stop_codon   407096   407098   .   -   0   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001290344.6"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
chr19   HAVANA   UTR   409006   409170   .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001322986.5"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
chr19   HAVANA   UTR   405438   407098   .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001290344.6"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
chr19   HAVANA   UTR   408362   408401   .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000183186.7"; transcript_id "ENST00000332235.7"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "C2CD4C"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "C2CD4C-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001290344.6"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000328677.4"; transcript_support_level "2"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS45890.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000180534.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000451789.3";
```

*Note:* The string "`exon_number n`" appears in lines of *all feature types* (field 3) except "`gene`" and "`transcript`", so the calculation should be specific for lines with "`exon`" in field 3 *ONLY*.

---

**Sample lines from my actual file**:

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    11869   12227   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00002234944.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003582793.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00002312635.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      12010   13670   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12010   12057   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12179   12227   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001671638.2"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12697   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00001758273.2"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12975   13052   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 4; exon_id "ENSE00001799933.2"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   13374   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 5; exon_id "ENSE00001746346.2"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13453   13670   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 6; exon_id "ENSE00001863096.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  gene    14404   29570   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      14404   29570   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    29534   29570   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001890219.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    24738   24891   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003507205.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    18268   18366   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00003477500.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    17915   18061   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 4; exon_id "ENSE00003565697.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    17606   17742   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 5; exon_id "ENSE00003475637.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    17233   17368   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 6; exon_id "ENSE00003502542.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    16858   17055   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 7; exon_id "ENSE00003553898.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    16607   16765   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 8; exon_id "ENSE00003621279.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    15796   15947   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 9; exon_id "ENSE00002030414.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    15005   15038   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 10; exon_id "ENSE00001935574.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    14404   14501   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000227232.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000488147.1"; gene_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "WASH7P"; transcript_type "unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "WASH7P-001"; exon_number 11; exon_id "ENSE00001843071.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000958.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002839.1";
chr1    ENSEMBL gene    17369   17436   .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000278267.1"; gene_type "miRNA"; gene_name "MIR6859-1"; level 3;
```

**Desired output based on my sample:**

```
6.66667
```

Since there are 3 exons for `ENST00000456328.2`, 6 exons for `ENST00000450305.2`, and 11 exons for `ENST00000488147.1` ~ **(3 + 6 + 11)/3 = 6.66667**

---

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS**

**(i)** I tried to print a list field 9 for all lines having "`exon`" in field 3. The following outputs `gene_id 1194547`:

```
if [ $3 == "exon" ]; then
    awk '{a[$9]++}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' file
fi
```

I believe this means my code is only counting the first part of column 9: `gene_id`. Unfortunately, I cannot get an average of one number.

**(ii)** I tried to print all lines having "`exon`" in field 3, then count the number of times `exon_number` appeared for a unique "`transcript_id`", but my knowledge of `awk` is very weak right now so I feel the script is way off. The following outputs a list of unique `gene_id`s and their respective counts such that each line of the output file looks something like this `"ENSG00000242201.3"; 1`, `"ENSG00000132478.9"; 41`, `"ENSG00000155099.7"; 34`:

```
awk '$3=="exon" {print $0}' file | awk '{count[$10]++} END {for (word in count) print word, count[word]}'
```

The counts produced are inaccurate because they simply add up the lines of all the same `gene_id`s as *exons*. This means that `ENSG00000183186.7` may be found/counted `47` times in the file, but this *gene* actually produces many differently sized transcripts, due to alternative splicing (biological relevance of this problem), and the code misses this. It should be specific to "`transcript_id`", not "`gene_id`".

**(iii)** This code is a work in progress and will need lots of reworking. I tried to (1) extract field 9 only if field 3 contained the string `exon`, (2) split the "`;`" separated list and extract *only* the highest value `exon_number n` for each unique "`transcript_id`", and then (3) calculate the *average* number of exons per transcript.

```
awk '$3 == "exon" {print $9}' file
#step needed here to split the “;” separated fields $9 to extract the max exon_number
awk '{ total += $1 } END { print total/NR }' file
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `The output should be ...`  Could you please _show_ the expected output? For the presented input, which number would that be? Could you explain how to calculate that number or how to parse the input? There are many skilled bash programmers here - but most (like me) will not know what is a GTF file and how to parse it.

Comment: So what I understand: A "exonic feature" is a line that has `$3=="exon"`. How do you determine how many "exons" one "exonic feature" has? Ie. the first the line `exon   409006` has 4 exons, right? Why 4? I see the line with `exon   409006` has `exon_number 1;`, is the value `1` somehow multiplied by something?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I appreciate you really trying to understand this problem. Yes, we can determine that a line is an exonic feature if ```$3=="exon"```. You can determine how many "exons" an "exonic feature" has by looking in column 9; look for ```exon_number``` in the ";" separated list. I would like the *maximum* number only to use in the average calculation.

Comment: But for the input you presented, the first exonic feature has only `exon_number 1;`? So why does it have 4 exons? (`split the “;”` just regex it `sed 's/.*exon_number \([^;]*\).*//\1/'`)

Comment: @KamilCuk, take lines 3 and 4 of the sample GTF file I added at the beginning of the post as an example. Both are ```$3=="exon"```, both have nearly the exact same information *except* that one has ```exon_number 1``` and the other has ```exon_number 2```. I want to know that this specific feature has a total of "2 exons" and another feature has a total of "6 exons" and another "4 exons", and so on, so that I can average 2, 4, and 6.

Comment: So for _just the lines you presented_ the answer would be 1,5? The first `exon` line has 1, the second has 2? We are interested in the output _for the input you presented_.

Comment: @KamilCuk, unfortunately not. That exonic feature has a total of 2 exons. In that example, there are no other exonic features so we can't get an average using those numbers only. Would this be easier if I added my exact, less simplified GTF input?

Comment: So... `You can determine how many "exons" an "exonic feature" has by looking in column 9;` this is the part that I don't understand. how are exonic features grouped/identified? By gene_id? From the new input: exonic feature with gene_id="ENSG00000227232.5" has 11 exons? `"ENSG00000223972.5"` has 6? `"ENSG00000223972.5"` has 3? Avarage is 11+3+6/3?

Comment: I added a more detailed example (an actual snippet from the GTF file I'm working with) to my question. Hopefully that makes it easier to understand. I'm always open to more suggestions to improve my question for your ease of access, so fire away.

Comment: @KamilCuk, not just ```gene_id```. That is why my attempts that use "gene_id" only are incorrectly grouping large numbers of exons together. I believe it must be linked to ```transcript_id```, mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I still do not get the whole story. So anyway:

```
# extract the lines with 3rd column equal to "exon"
awk '$3 == "exon"' |
# Extract the interesting parts with a regex. I like `sed` more, so I'll use it.
# extract the transcript_id and exon number
# separator is ';'
sed -n 's/.*transcript_id \([^;]*\).*exon_number \([^;]*\).*/\1;\2/p' |
# because I noticed that number is equal to count of lines
# just count the lines with the same transcript_id
# (actually exon_number is ignored)
# and then calculate the average of the array
awk -F';' '{a[$1]++} END{for (i in a) {cnt++; sum += a[i]} print sum/cnt}'
# or you could also like get the highest number from exon_number with like
# awk ... '{ if (a[$1] < $2) a[$1]=$2 } ...'
```

For the input provided as [tested on repl the script outputs](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/WarlikeUnlawfulTitles#main.sh):

```
6.66667
```

I have left 3 commands above so it looks verbose, the same job can be done with a single awk script, which would be faster then a chain of 3 processes. Just use `gensub` in `awk` instead of `sed` and `split` in `awk` to split the input to an array inside awk.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you @KamilCuk!! Yes, counting the number of times ```transcript_id``` appears is a much easier solution than taking the max ```exon_number```. Wish I could have thought of that myself.

Comment: A bit late but I have calculated the number of exons per transcript based on the total number of transcripts provided by Biomart (Genome ref. 38). Biomart provides the rank of the exons after providing a list of transcripts. I took the last exons wich also inform the total number of exons. Then, I calculated the average across all transcripts, the number was 6.7854. In case this helps :)